# Python Popen fails to run msiexec

Tags: python

I'm trying to install a Windows MSI with Python like this but it fails.

```
Popen(shlex.split('msiexec.exe /I Z:/osd46271_2020_RC2.msi /L* install.log'))
```

[image]

The install.log file is created but nothing is written there.  The exact same command running in Command Prompt works fine.  I'm running as Administrator on Windows 2016 with Python 3.8.2.  I have used similar code on the same system in the past.  I can't figure out what would be breaking this.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out already.  I have to use four backslashes with `shlex.split` so it will be turned into two backslashes.  This is kind of ugly, but it works.

```
Popen(shlex.split('msiexec.exe /I Z:\\\\osd46271_2020_RC2.msi /L* install.log'))
```

Comment: You could also use a raw string with 2 backslashes: `r'msiexec.exe /I Z:\\osd46271_2020_RC2.msi /L* install.log'`